# Get Certificate name after installation

Tags: c#, certificate

I installed a certificate with file name let say "Certificate.pfx".

After installing it, when I checked the Internet Explorer -> Content -> Certificates ,it's name appeared to be "cert".

Now, I have the location of the certificate file, I need it's name when it will be installed.

I am using C#.

Comment: How are you using c#?

Comment: Did you research that?

Comment: I did but didn't get a method to get the name.

Comment: Can somebody answer this..?